# salesforcerest.update not working in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: api, salesforce, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am doing Salesforce update operation using Salesforce Rest connector in wso2 ei. problem here is record not updated, it shows below exception after forming request payload.
**Exception**:

|`**TID: [-1234] [] [2019-12-06 05:03:05,191] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} -  #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. MessageID: urn:uuid:33275d28-c55d-4a9e-bbcd-17d60cc38d1e {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-12-06 05:03:05,192] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator} -  Error creating JSON Payload from source Lead {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator}**`

Code Snippet:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestImageAPI" context="/imageapi">
   <resource methods="GET" protocol="http https">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom" separator=",**, " description="FaultSequence">
            <property name="=====TestImageAPI=====" value="called===="/>
         </log>
         <property name="ValuationId" value="00Q5500000AGHikEAH" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="First_Image_Name__c" value="cbimage" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ObjectName" value="Lead" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json" description="Form Response Payload">
            <format>{"Lead_Type__c":"$1"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg value="Phone"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="fieldAndValue" expression="json-eval($.)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="===FirstImagepayload=====" expression="$ctx:fieldAndValue"/>
         </log>
         <sequence key="QRSag_VBSalesforceInitializer" description="Load Configurations"/>
         <salesforcerest.init>
            <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
            <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
            <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
            <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
            <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
            <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
            <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
            <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
            <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
         </salesforcerest.init>
         <property name="SalesforceAccessToken" expression="json-eval($.access_token)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('SalesforceAccessToken'))" scope="transport" type="STRING" description="Authorization"/>
         <salesforcerest.update>
            <sObjectName>{$ctx:ObjectName}</sObjectName>
            <Id>{$ctx:ValuationId}</Id>
            <fieldAndValue>{$ctx:fieldAndValue}</fieldAndValue>
         </salesforcerest.update>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Note: Added Salesforce Rest connector in both server as well as ESB Project

Could anyone please give me a solution??

Comment: Can you send wire enabled logs [1] for your request? It seems the error occurs with the payloadFactory mediator before coming to the connector. 
[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs

Comment: Hi @prabushisamarakoon
Thank you for your reply. i'll give you wire log soon. can you please look into the below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the above mentioned use case. FYI,

```
<property description="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('SalesforceAccessToken'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                                                <payloadFactory description="Form Response Payload" media-type="json">
                                                    <format>{"First_Image_Name__c":"$1"}</format>
                                                    <args>
                                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:First_Image_Name__c"/>
                                                    </args>
                                                </payloadFactory>
                                                <log level="custom">
                                                    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="===FirstImagepayload====="/>
                                                </log>
                                                <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="fieldAndValue" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                                                <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="false"/>
                                                <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:instance_url,'/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Product2/',$ctx:StockID)" name="uri.var.ImageUpload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                                <property description="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('SalesforceAccessToken'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                                                <log level="custom">
                                                    <property expression="$ctx:uri.var.ImageUpload" name="===SalesforceLink========="/>
                                                </log>
                                                <call description="ImageuploadEndpoint">
                                                    <endpoint>
                                                        <http method="patch" uri-template="{uri.var.ImageUpload}"/>
                                                    </endpoint>
                                                </call>
                                                <log level="full" separator="=== First Image Name Update Response ==="/>
```